# keycloak JWT token contain "\" when mapping multivalued json array attribute

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services, keycloak-rest-api, keycloak-connect

I have assign a client scope for my client with a mapper which is multivalued. For example "school"

In the user, I create attribute as follow:

school:
{"student_No":"1000","teacher_No":"50","male":"800","female":"250"}

school:
{"student_No":"2000","teacher_No":"100","male":"1600","female":"500"}

However when I obtain JWT access token, the payload show this after decode using JWT.io:

"school": [

"
{\"student_No\":\"1000\",\"teacher_No\":\"50\",\"male\":\"800\",\"female\":\"250\"}",

"{\"student_No\":\"2000\",\"teacher_No\":\"100\",\"male\":\"1600\",\"female\":\"500\"}"

]

I found "\" is added within the array. I don't know why it is generated, how can it be removed in the JTW?

Comment: That's not a JSON Web Token. It's stringified JSON. It it easily parsed back to JSON.

Comment: thanks for the comment, actually I'm ok with the stringify, I just want to remove the "\" in the array , like "{"XXX":"123","YYY":"456"}" is ok for me. I'm confused why would I get a "\" within it when decoding the JWT payload

Comment: Same. Some products stringify the results - most - don't. I see you've modified your question. If JWT.io is parsing back a stringified payload then there is something wrong with either keycloak or the way you're feeding data in.

Answer (score 1):

Check your mapper config carefully. It seems that Keycloak stores your JSON as a string and then returns it to the client